# MongoDB YAML "Unrecognized option: security.ldap.servers"

Tags: mongodb, ldap

I am running MongoDB v.4.4.0 on Linux CentOS 7. I am having trouble setting up the YAML config file for for security and authorization. When I have the below config file I only receive an error saying "Unrecognized option: security.ldap.servers". What is wrong with my config?

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/home/mongo/mongodb/logs/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true

storage:
  dbPath: "/home/mongo/mongodb/data/db"

net:
  bindIp: localhost, 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

security:
#  authorization: enabled
  ldap:
    servers: "ldap"
    bind:
      queryUser: user
      queryPassword: pass
    transportSecurity: none
    userToDNMapping: '[{match: "(.+)", ldapQuery: "o=int,c=com?uid?sub?userPrincipalName={0}@ldap.xxx.com"}]'
    authz:
      queryTemplate: '{USER}?memberOf?base'
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: 'PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-1'
```

Thanks

Comment: Should work. I suggest to open a case at https://jira.mongodb.org

Answer (score 0):

You received that error because security.ldap.servers is available only in MongoDB Enterprise. See the documentation section (e.g security.ldap.servers) [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/configuration-options/). I guess you are trying it in community edition. However, I found some useful [documentation](https://github.com/percona/percona-server-mongodb), which says free, compatiable and drop-in replacement MongoDB Community Edition with enterprise-grade features. I didn't try it personally yet. Additionally, you may have a look into [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/configure-ldap-sasl-openldap/). Thanks